# How to turn any program reading from standard input into a server using systemd?

Tags: systemd

According to https://www.launchd.info/ (the cookbook section):

> launchd makes it very easy to create servers. In fact, launchd can turn any program reading from standard input into a server.

Since systemd is more or less a clone of / heavily inspired by launchd, I suspect that the same functionality might be present there as well. However, a brief look through the docs and an equally brief google-ing later I came up empty handed.
Is this possible and if yes: how so?

## Alternatives considered

There is of course good old (x)inetd which does exactly this. There is also [websocketd](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd) which I found during this research, which seems handy. However, I'd rather not have to learn yet another config language for this.

Comment: You can start any long running task using `systemd` mechanism. Take a look at [this link](http://git.haproxy.org/?p=haproxy.git;a=blob_plain;f=admin/systemd/haproxy.service.in;hb=18c7d8393411c9c91d211060599c5dea83b016e5) to get an idea of how to do so.

Comment: @Meysam How does that incorporate redirecting stdin and stdout to the network socket?

Comment: The answer you posted below is rightly the answer. `socket` does that sort of reading from input as you mentioned. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Of course shortly after posting this question I googled some more and with inetd in the search terms I discovered [this nicely written blog post](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/inetd.html), according to which you need a `.socket` file for everything socket related and the usual `.service` file, albeit with a twist (see the note at the end). Without further ado, here's the example from the blog post:

### sshd.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH Socket for Per-Connection Servers

[Socket]
ListenStream=22
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

### sshd@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH Per-Connection Server

[Service]
ExecStart=-/usr/sbin/sshd -i
StandardInput=socket
```

Worthy of note is the `@` which I assume turns this into an *instantiated* service.

I haven't yet tried this, so buyer beware.